# Replicate Oracle db into h2 for unit test (spring-boot application)

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, h2

i need some information about a task i'm trying to solve,
Is there a method for replicate an Oracle database into an h2 database for testing my application?
This issue comes because i need to replicate every time my Oracle structure in the test database before testing simple crud operation like save/update ecc, so i can also test entities structure.
I know this is not so simple because i can sure create a .sql file for initialize the in-memory db but i need something that every time, let me use the term, pull the script from Oracle (because currently structure are changing often)  and use for create h2 at runtime.
If all of this is utopia i sure understand and i will resign myself :) thank you.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Take a look at Flyway Db migration tool. You can have custom step to migrate data from oracle to H2 and run the flyway migrate at the start of the application.

Comment: The problem with unit testing with distinct databases is that... you don't test in fact...

Comment: Ideally, you'd need to use modern Oracle Pluggable Database (PDB) clone process: 5 seconds to duplicate an empty database. Less than 20 seconds when you've got reasonable quantity of data. You should aim for 19c which grants you 3 free PDBs. Hence my initial question to ensure you would be able to go this way :)

Comment: Oracle database version is 18.0 Enterprise , @SushilBehera i looked at flyway an is really cool, i try it and i'll let you know. thanks ! :)

Comment: @loic yes but in the Oracle db there are a lot of domain values that i need to use for testing my application, if i don't pre-load this data my unit tests are ok but not really useful , also because if my entities structure are wrong with h2 test i don't replicate those errors

Comment: If you just need the structure and not the data, you can clone the PDB without the data, just the metadata (i.e. the structure): create pluggable database unittests from master no data;

Comment: @loic i need data also with the structure of the Oracle db. i need something that pull schema and script into my application and use them for creating h2 database each time i unit test my application

Comment: @MichaelCauduro, I can't help you here, I understand your needs but I don't see the value of introducing 2 new technologies to do so (H2, the replication one) as it would introduce additional management and potential bugs/unexpected behaviours as well as (previously said) it could at some point make you think you are really testing while it's not. I used to learn it the hard way, so good luck :)